# How to update the database using sqlform through a service call

Tags: web2py

I wanted to know how to update the database using sqlform through a service call. for example

db.py contains

```
db.define_table('person',
Field('name'),
Field('email'))
```

controller contains

```
@service.run
def display_form():
form = SQLFORM(db.person)
if form.accepts(request.vars):
    return "success"
else:
    return "failure"
```

The http post variable is sent as data = {"name":"xyz", "email":"xyz@gmail.com"}

I would like to know whether I am sending the post variables correctly. I always get the failure message. WHY IS THE DB NOT GETTING UPDATED. Actually I would like to do this with form = auth.register(). I need to enter the auth table values through a service call. but this is long way to go.

### Update

This is the way I am posting.

```
url = "http://example.com/myapp/mycontroller/api/person"
data = {"name":"peter","email":"peter@gmail.com"}
datatosend = urllib.urlencode(data)
request = urllib2.Request(url,datatosend)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

but the POST method in api is not seeing the person at all.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a form via `SQLFORM`, a special hidden `_formname` field is added to the form. If the posted data does not include a matching `_formname` field, the `form.accepts()` method will fail. In place of the default formname, you can specify your own, and add it to the posted data:

```
@service.run
def display_form():
    request.vars._formname = 'myform'
    form = SQLFORM(db.person)
    if form.accepts(request.vars, formname='myform'):
        return 'success'
    else:
        return 'failure'
```

However, a much simpler method is to avoid the form altogether and directly insert the record (still taking advantage of the validation process by using the `validate_and_insert` method):

```
@service.run
def display_form():
    return db.person.validate_and_insert(**request.vars)
```

This will return the inserted record ID if successful or validation errors otherwise.

An alternative to `@service.run` is the new [RESTful web services](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/09#RESTful-Web-Services) functionality:

```
@request.restful()
def api():
    def POST(tablename, **fields):
        if not tablename == 'person': raise HTTP(400)
        return db.person.validate_and_insert(**fields)
    return locals()
```

Then insert a record via a POST request to:

http://mydomain.com/myapp/mycontroller/api/person

Comment: thanks anthony, but could you please explain me why my functions as shown in the questions are not doing the expected.

Comment: anthony, I tried restful webservice but it is not taking the request. It is not identifying the tablename atall. I am using urllib2 to POST.

Comment: See updated answer above. The @request.restful version works for me - perhaps there is something wrong with your POST request.